# Flink TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction

Tags: apache-flink

As the [doc](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka-0.11/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaProducer011.java) says, `TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction` is introduced in Flink 1.4.0 to enable end-to-end exactly-once semantic. I have two questions about this abstract class `TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction` and its subclass `FlinkKafkaProducer011` (source code is [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/sink/TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction.java) and [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka-0.11/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaProducer011.java)).

1. `TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction` has a `abort` method to abort a transaction. So, what is the case that the `abort` method is called ? Specifically, will it be called after the commit process has begun, which means giving up on current transaction and exactly-once semantic ? I am asking this because, as the comment says, this is a recommended base class for all of the SinkFunction that intend to implement exactly-once semantic.
2. [Flink documentation](https://flink.apache.org/features/2018/03/01/end-to-end-exactly-once-apache-flink.html) says:

> The starting of a checkpoint represents the "pre-commit" phase of our two-phase commit protocol.

This makes me believe that the implementation of `preCommit` should handle the checkpointing of all operators but `FlinkKafkaProducer011` implements `preCommit` like this :

```
@Override
    protected void preCommit(KafkaTransactionState transaction) throws FlinkKafka011Exception {
        switch (semantic) {
            case EXACTLY_ONCE:
            case AT_LEAST_ONCE:
                flush(transaction);
                break;
            case NONE:
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented semantic");
        }
        checkErroneous();
    }
```

and `flush` is like this:

```
private void flush(KafkaTransactionState transaction) throws FlinkKafka011Exception {
        if (transaction.producer != null) {
            transaction.producer.flush();
        }
        long pendingRecordsCount = pendingRecords.get();
        if (pendingRecordsCount != 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Pending record count must be zero at this point: " + pendingRecordsCount);
        }

        // if the flushed requests has errors, we should propagate it also and fail the checkpoint
        checkErroneous();
    }
```

It seems that no checkpointing is handled in `preCommit`. So, do I get it wrong somewhere ?

Comment: The slides and video for this Flink Forward talk should help you out: https://berlin-2017.flink-forward.org/index.html%3Fp=2735.html

Comment: Thanks for the link  @DavidAnderson. I think the slides and videos explain the exactly-once problem better than the doc. However, the code above does not accord with the explanation because checkpointing is not handled in `preCommit` method as page 15 of the slide shows.

Answer (score 1):

1. `abort` is called for example on currently on going transaction, that hasn't been pre-committed, when sink function is being closed. Example scenario is there was some failure on a different node in the cluster, job is failing over, so we are aborting the current transaction (in order to recover from a previous successful checkpoint)
2. `flush` in Kafka when used on transactional `KafkaProducer` has basically a semantic of pre-commit. That's why `preCommit(...)` method is using it for both `EXACTLY_ONCE` and `AT_LEAST_ONCE`.